# How to detect UI elements for Hybrid App

Tags: selenium-webdriver, hybrid-mobile-app

I have used UI Automator Viewer. It's not detecting UI elements in Hybrid App.

I am looking for some spy tool (like "appium inspector" and "uiautomatorviewer" ) for Hybrid application.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect elements in chrome. Set your device to debug mode. connect device to system. Open chrome and type `chrome://inspect/#devices`. Right click on the element you want to detect and select inspect element.

Comment: Suman,I tried with debug mode in chrome it detects device.I want to detect UI elements of hybrid App,In the elements in the App nothing is shown.so how to see the App and the UI elements of that?

Comment: If you are not able to detect using chrome. Use UIAutomator. You can find it in Android > sdks > tools.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Selendroid. It's Selenium for Android apps - native, hybrid, mobile.

http://selendroid.io/hybrid.html

There you have Selendroid Inspector for detecting elements:
http://selendroid.io/inspector.html

Comment: Does Selendroid Inspector detect hybrid UI elements? Does in Chrome inspect elements detects hybrid UI elements?  As Hybrid and Native UI elements are different.

Comment: Yes it does, it works like selenium, first you need to find a webview, then switch to it. And after this you can work normally as with selenium.  "Web View Source Code
For displaying the html source code of a web view please follow these steps:

Select in the UI hierarchy the webview you want to inspect and press the ctrl key (this keeps the selection of the element).
select the tab Html Source"

Comment: Nat,Can you please provide me a link where exactly how i can find the webview,as i am new to selenium.Further how it helps me to detect UI elements.

Comment: http://selendroid.io/inspector.html here you have all info that you need to do this.